# ImageMagick - Turn image transparent via color

Tags: image, imagemagick

Well, I have this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/78yU0.png and I want to make it transparent. By that I mean I want the pink background gone...

However, it's long and doing pixel wand would take a while. Can I use ImageMagick and do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if by magick:

```
convert 78yU0.png -fuzz "2%" -transparent #ff00ff transparent.png
```

Out of interest when looking at your image in gimp to get the colour of the pink it looks like your image is not correctly placed on the canvas. It still seems to work but might cause problems later?

Comment: What does the 2% do? Not sure what you mean by the GIMP question.

Comment: @weka The %2 is the amount the colour can vary from #ff00ff. In your case it could have been left out as your colours are blocks; but I left it in as others may have slight variations on the colour they are trying to remove. The larger the % the larger the colour range effected.